# Jmeter create article automatically to drupal8 app

Tags: jmeter, drupal-8

I want to add new article on drupal8 web app with jmeter script. 
I can not find the new article with response code 200.
In my theory, jmeter could simulate manual operation. So, it should initialize web site perf test context.

Question:

- How to find web dynamic parameters?
- what's wrong with my request parameter?

Context:

1. [Jmeter structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZAGY.png)

Get New article page and extract parameter, then publish article to web app.
Here we get response code 200, but can not find new article in Drupal app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with tool [badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/).

1. run manual operation on badboy
2. get jmeter script from : File >> Export to Jmeter...
3. find http request sampler which contains parameters list we need
4. copy it to my jmeter script and run

Jmeter + Badboy save me from repetitions work on web app

Answer (score 1):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Response Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, it doesn't do any checks for errors in the response body. Normally people use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) (or other Assertion types, check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) for details) to conditionally set pass or fail statuses for Samplers.

With regards to your problem my expectation is that the request is failing due to missing or improperly implemented **correlation** of the dynamic parameters like `form_build_id` or `form_token`, please double check your test logic and ensure that these parameters are being properly handled using [JMeter Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors).

Comment: Thanks for your attention to this matter.    we get http request parameters with **badboy** and it works well!! Jmeter is awesome, we can create article automatically on drupal8 app now!